# Run a qsub command in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, grep, find, qsub

I am using Centos on a HPC to run my code. I typically have a folder that contains a run_calc File, which is what I want to run as:

```
qsub run_calc
```

Now I want to write a script "submit_all.sh" that submits all run_calc files in all the subfolders in their current directory and not from the from a parent folder where I runt the submit_all.sh script.

I found similar questions posted here [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943022/run-a-qsub-command-from-a-parent-folder-to-all-directories-below-with-a-file-d) and here [Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839749/how-to-qsub-jobs-to-the-cluster-from-the-parent-directory-for-the-subdirectories)
that seems to be a partial answer to this question. I am not confident just submitting scripts until I found a solution which is why I ask:

In the second link I found this solution:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
    cd "$i"
    qsub submit.sh
    cd ..
done
```

were "i" was a list of folders with the names 1-100. Is it somehow possible to use find to create a list of all the subdirectories and path it to the for loop? How would i deal with subsubdirectories? Would I be able to change the cd .. statement such that I always go back to the parent folder directly in that case?

I fond this solution here: [Solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276263/how-to-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command-on-specific-file)

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `find /var/www -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`; do
   cd $i
   # do something here
done
```

But I do not understand what is going on? Is it possible to change the above script to the only dive into folders containing a run_calc File and also include subsubdirectries?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `find` in a `for loop` with caution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `bash` as your shell:

```
$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' 
while read -r fname ; 
do 
    pushd $(dirname "${fname}") > /dev/null
    qsub run_calc 
    popd > /dev/null 
done < <(find . -type f -name 'run_calc')
```

`find . -type f -name 'run_calc'` finds all paths to file `run_calc` inside the current directory and its subdirectories. This is input for the `while loop`.

`pushd, popd` are `bash` specific, and adds in or pops out of directory stack.

Comment: Whenn i submit this script i get "qsuball.sh: line 1: $: command not found
". if i delete line one the script is executed, but has not result it seems. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What's in line#1 of your script ?Content of the script excludes this line:  `$ cat ./test.sh`. I hope you are not including that.

Comment: I deleted the cat ./test.sh part but left the $ somehow... unfortunately if i start with #!/bin/bash it still doesnt work. at least there are no new jobs in the queue if i have a look at it? Thank you for taking the time btw!

Comment: Check that this command gives you the right path for your run_calc file: `find /var/www -type f -name 'run_calc'`. If it does, then go to one of those directories and execute `qsub run_calc` and see if that actually works.

Comment: If i run: `find /var/www -type f -name 'run_calc'` there is no error but, nothing is found. I just get a new empty command line if that makes sense.

Comment: If you don’t find any “run_calc” file then how will qsub run it ? Find looks for “run_calc” file inside “/var/www” ?

Comment: Dear iamauser, i am really a beginner when it comes to linux systems. I am able to do easy file manipulations with vim and navigated copy etc.... Unfortunately i do not know what the “/var/www" directory is. What i want to do is to search all the sub directories contained in my current working directory and submit the 'run_calc Files'. If possible i would also want to include deeper directories (sub sub directories) . I can assure you that all the sub directories inside the working dir where i test the command contained a 'run_calc File'! I could submit these files manually!

Comment: You had “/var/www” in your question, that’s why i put that in the answer. If you want to find files under the current directory and subdirectories, then replace “/var/www” with “.”  (dot). Also see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, i copy and pasted from the links i provided without really understanding what i read. Thank you, it seems to work now!

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in `find . -type d`
do ( cd "$d"
     if test ! -f run_calc; then continue; fi
     qsub run_calc
) done
```

`( commnds )` execute `commands` in a separate process and effect of `cd` does not "leak".

Comment: The Answer of iamuser seems to work. Just out of intrest, is there any benefit to this solution? Thank you for answering btw!

Comment: It is not bash specific.